# How to get 1st symbol after PSP

Tags: assembly, tasm

How much space PSP holds in memory? I mean, i want to jump over PSP and get 1st symbol after PSP into DS.

```
;print
mov    ah,2
mov    dl,ds:[PSP] 
int 21h
```

Answer (score 0):

256 bytes. Though I don't know what you expect to be after it. Afaik that is not specified.

PSP Segments are linked via the "parent" field in the PSP.